# Orders import export

Tags: orders, import, export, importexport

Hi is there any way to import and export orders? By default  can import and export the products and customers data but not he orders.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to export or import orders, anyways there is a [SOAP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) and a [REST](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) API which you can access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a mod instead of coding yourself then http://amasty.com/efficient-order-export.html is pretty good from our experience.  Pretty easy to tailor to suit your needs.